# jquery transition effect on block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add an effect on a div, where once you hover over the block the block will move up. I'm using Jquery transitions as I'm aware that anything under ie10 doesnt really support css transitions. At the moment I can get it to move but there is no effect on the movement (just using css). I'm not sure how I would start to add the jquery transition.

At the moment I got it so that once you hover over the block it adds a class.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".container").hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("animated-effect");
    });
});
```

Heres my jsfiddle, I can't manage to get the code to work something up with my js:
http://jsfiddle.net/4bgj4959/

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle. You also said "Im using Jquery transitions", but I don't see any transitions other than a toggleClass.

Comment: Yeah im not sure how to add it

Comment: Select it from the box in the upper left corner titled frameworks & extensions.

Comment: Additionally... if you want to give a time to your toggleClass function... jquery-ui could help: _http://jsfiddle.net/4bgj4959/8/_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `animate` method. Note that `hover` method takes two parameters, the second parameter is for `onmouseout` (when you are done hovering).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      top: '20px'
    })
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      top: '0px'
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #00c;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you code is working you didn't include `jquery` see updated `fiddle`
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4bgj4959/3/)

Comment: He wants to *animate* the effect, he knows the JS works

Comment: @ Jacob Gray given demo link has no `jquey` included